# Redshift - Query with 300K of values in the 'in' part of query

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena

I need to query data in a table in redshift with a lot of (around 300K) values in the `in` part of the condition and store the result into a CSV.

Eg. `select * from table where column_name in ('123','456','678',.....)`
values in the `in` part are around 300K and result data would have 5 million rows.
The table is already sorted on the same column that I'm searching for.

What would be the most optimal way?

I have tried below things:

1. Get the data full table to CSV and run the query on AWS Athena. Athena is unable to run the query at all.

> **It gave this error:** Something went wrong. Please retry.

2. Used an UNLOAD query directly on redshift. It takes too much time.

Comment: how is your table distributed across nodes: even, by column...??

Comment: single node only :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COPY` to load the 300k values into a temp table and then use a join instead of an `IN ()` list.

`UNLOAD` is the best way to extract the data, 5 million rows is too much data to extract as a `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a better way. Apparently creating a temp table using a CTAS query and unloading the temp table to S3 takes a shorter time.

Directly unloading the query to S3 took around an hour and still running. Creating a temp table took 4 min and S3 unload of temp took 3 min.